# Sqoop import from oracle to hdfs: No more data to read from socket

Tags: sql, oracle, hadoop, sqoop, ojdbc

I'm trying to import data from Oracle to HDFS using Sqoop. Oracle version: 10.2.0.2
Table is not having constraints. When I mention number of mappers(-m) and --split-by parameters, it's showing the error: No more data to read from socket. If I mention -m 1(setting the number of mappers as 1), it's running, but taking too much time.
Sqoop command:
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID --username *uname* --password *pwd*  --table abc.market_price --target-dir /ert/etldev/etl/market_price -m 4 --split-by MNTH_YR

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the num of mappers why dont you try using --direct ..

what does it show then??

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID --username uname --password pwd --table abc.market_price --target-dir /ert/etldev/etl/market_price --direct
```

or

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID --username uname --password pwd --table abc.market_price --target-dir /ert/etldev/etl/market_price --split-by MNTH_YR --direct
```

Comment: I'm getting the below error:
 17/08/14 14:30:07 WARN oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Unable to determine whether the Oracle table *table_name* is an index-organized table.
Error:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Try giving the table name including the schema name.. change the case and try again..